# Use my own db with windows8 and SQLiteMetro

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have an existing SQLite.db that I want to use in a Windows8 application using SQLiteMetro.  I have a working sample application that uses the following:

```
using SQLiteMetro; 

Database db =new Database(Path.Combine( Windows. Storage .ApplicationData. Current. LocalFolder. Path, "test.db"));
```

How do I add my own existing db (e.g. "test.db"  that has 1000 records) to the Win8/Metro project so the db can be accessed by the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place it in your app's local state.  Apps local state folders are located by default in `%localappdata%\packages\<packageid>\LocalState`.

You can then use syntax like ...

```
var root = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(root, "test.db"))
```

Good article on [Sqlite for Windows 8 Metro style apps](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/05/20/using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx) and more information on [Application Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh464917).

Comment: Thanks JP, I added the db to the project and marked the db as "content", just referred to the file as "test.db" and it appears to work as normal.  Thanks for the article hints.